# ¿Cómo intercambiar día y mes en una fecha (objeto datetime)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Tengo un archivo de ***xlsx*** con una columna que contiene fechas (con el tipo *Fecha* de Excel):

[image: datos]

El problema es que están almacenadas de forma errónea ya que el mes debería ser el día y viceversa, es decir, tengo:

> ***d/m/y H:M***

cuando debería ser:

> **m/d/y H:M**

Al momento de obtener las fechas con **`openpyxl`** uso esta conversión:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'd1.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
filas = [ [cell.value  for cell in row ] for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset= 1)]
for fila in filas:
     fila[0] = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(fila[0], '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'),'%m/%d/%y%H:%M')
```

pero no funciona, el mes debería ser Enero siempre, pero sigue tomando el día como mes.

Comment: Hola Luis, deberías aclarar un poco más la pregunta. ¿Qué biblioteca usas para leer el archivo, Pandas, openpyxl, etc? El problema se produce al leer los datos escritos con Excel mediante  Python o al leer datos escritos con Python mediante Excel? ¿Las fechas son cadenas, tipo fecha de Excel, datetime de Python, etc? Agrega el código con el que lees o escribes el archivo, al menos la mínima parte para reproducir el problema.

Comment: @FJSevilla es openpyxl son tipo  datetime entonces el problema es de excel te da el valor al revez los dias y meses como el primer dia de cada mes en vez de los dias de enero por que desde el archivo excel cambio el formato de la fecha y dice 1 de mayo en vez 5 de enero

Comment: Luis a ver si estoy en lo correcto: tienes una columna en Excel con formato de fecha (no cadenas) que es incorrecta (tiene el día intercambiado por el mes).  Al leer con openpyxl la fecha es pasada automáticamente a Datetime (lógicamente arrastrando el error) y lo que deseas es intercambiar el día por el mes en esos datos de tipo Datetime ¿Es correcto?.

Comment: @FJSevilla es correcto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es intercambiar el día por el mes en una fecha almacenada en un objeto `datetime`puedes hacerlo como pretendes pero tienes que intercambiarlos en el proceso.

Vamos a partir desde un ejemplo con la fecha *"2 de Diciembre de 2017 14:45"*:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> fecha = datetime(2017, 12, 2, 14, 45)
>>> fecha
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 2, 14, 45)
```

Ahora solo hay que pasar la fecha a cadena por ejemplo con `fecha.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')`. El siguiente paso es pasar de nuevo a `datetime` pero intercambiando día y mes aplicando el formato `'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M'` en este caso:

```
>>> fecha =  datetime.strptime(fecha.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'), '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M')
>>> fecha
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 12, 14, 45)
```

Aunque esto funciona es más simple usar el método [`datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
>>> fecha = datetime(2017, 12, 2, 14, 45)
>>> fecha
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 2, 14, 45)
>>> fecha = fecha.replace(day = fecha.month, month = fecha.day)
>>> fecha
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 12, 14, 45)
```

Comment: funciono los dos métodos gracias por compartir una alternativa mas simple

Comment: De nada @LuisAlbertoAcosta . He editado la pregunta agregando las aclaraciones de los comentarios para que quede más claro problema concreto, siente libre de modificar algo si no estas de acuerdo. Creo que la pregunta puede ser interesante para más usuarios. Un saludo.